# Когда последний раз заходил

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Почему изменился дизайн профилей людей и теперь не видно, когда кто-то последний раз заходил на сайт?

Comment: Попробовал переадресовать ваш вопрос администрации.

Comment: Это надо [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) спрашивать. Наверно, уже много раз об этом спрашивали.

Comment: @oleedd, спасибо, нашёл и правда, [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive).